# Python: Read a line from a file then remove it with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, line, python-multithreading

I have this program that uses Python threading to read different lines in a file, if it reads a duplicate line then reads another one, and once It has read it, removes the line from the file. The problem is that whenever it reads the file It doesn't update the file, or I'm not quite sure what's happening. It can sometimes read the same line as before therefore breaking it. I'm not sure if my code is the most effective way to do this?

```
def read_tokens_list():
    tokens = []
    with open('inputTokens.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            tokens.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    return tokens

def worker(token_list):
    while True:
        token = random.choice(token_list)
        print(token)
        ver = open("Fullyverified.txt", "a+")
        ver.write(token + "\n")

        with open("inputTokens.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        with open("inputTokens.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != token:
                    f.write(line)
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    threads = []

    num_thread = input('Number of Threads: ')
    num_thread = int(num_thread)

    token_list = read_tokens_list()                     # read in the pokens.txt file
    random.shuffle(token_list)                          # shuffle the list into random order
    tokens_per_worker = len(token_list) // num_thread   # how many tokens from the list each worker will get (roughly)

    for i in range(num_thread):
        if ((i+1)<num_thread):
            num_tokens_for_this_worker = tokens_per_worker   # give each worker an even share of the list
        else:
            num_tokens_for_this_worker = len(token_list)     # except the last worker gets whatever is left

        # we'll give the first (num_tokens_for_this_worker) tokens in the list to this worker
        tokens_for_this_worker = token_list[0:num_tokens_for_this_worker]

        # and remove those tokens from the list so that they won't get used by anyone else
        token_list = token_list[num_tokens_for_this_worker:]

        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args= (tokens_for_this_worker, ))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lock.

something like:

```
from threading import Lock
# ...
lock = Lock()
# ...

def worker(token_list, lock = lock):
# ...
    with lock:
        with open("inputTokens.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        with open("inputTokens.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                if line.strip("\n") != token:
                    f.write(line)
# ...
```

The idea of the lock is to protect resources from being accessed by various threads simultaneously. So while one thread is working with the file, the others are waiting.

The next question is if this approach makes sense now, because depending of the size of your file, threads might be stuck waiting for the lock most of the time.

What about a database instead of a file? so you don't have to rewrite a full file, but just delete/update an entry